# replace \n to new line in string with php

Tags: php, character-encoding, special-characters, newline

I just want to replace "\n" characters to new line in a string using php, like that :

```
string 'foo\n\nbar'
```

to

```
string 'foo

bar`
```

Anybody have an idea ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

use `str_replace('\n', PHP_EOL, 'foo\n\nbar');`

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$string = 'foo\n\nbar';

$string = str_replace('\n', PHP_EOL, $string);

echo $string;
?>
```

Shows:

```
foo

bar
```

Comment: would be cool if you add `nl2br` option to your answer in the case that the text is to be displayed as HTML

Comment: **@Okeke Emmanuel Oluchukwu**, `nl2br` is already mentioned by **chandresh_cool**.

Comment: Oh my, really sorry about that @CORRUPT

Answer (score 1):

you can always Use

```
nl2br
```

function

Comment: It seems that the answer is replace the \n by PHP_EOL